# Volatility updating with Heston-Nandi model

Tags: beginner, mathematics, r, finance, numerical-methods

I'm trying to program a volatility updating rule using iteration. I start with the well-known Heston-Nandi model where the returns dynamics are:

$$
\left\{
  \begin{array}{rcl}
    R_{t+1} &=& r + \gamma h_{t+1} + \sqrt{h_{t+1}} z_{t+1}\\
    h_{t+1} &=& \beta_0 + \beta_1 h_t + \beta_2\left(z_t - \beta_3 \sqrt{h_t}\right)^2
  \end{array}
\right.
$$

where

- \$z_t\$ is an IID standard normal random variable
- \$h_t\$ is time-varying squared volatility
- \$\beta_0 > 0,\ \beta_1 \ge 0,\ \beta_2 \ge 0\$, and \$\gamma > -\frac{1}{2}\$.

I want to do is to write the code associate to the volatility updating rule, explained in this algorithm:

1. Define \$h_0 = c\$ equals the given unconditional variance  which is constant,
2. Iteration for \$t \in \{1, 2, \cdots, n\}\$:

   $$
   \left\{
     \begin{array}{rcl}
       h_{t+1} &=& \beta_0 + \beta_1 h_t + \beta_2\left(z_t - \beta_3 \sqrt{h_t}\right)^2 \\
       z_t     &=& \frac{[R_t - r - \gamma h_t]}{\sqrt{h_t}}
     \end{array}
   \right.
      $$

   to obtain the returns based proxy for spot variances \$(h_t^R)_t\$. Which yields an updating function that exclusively involves observation:

   $$ h_{t+1} = \beta_0 + \beta_1 h_t + \frac{\beta_2}{h_t} \left( R_t - r - (\beta_3 + \gamma)h_t \right)^2$$

My program is the following:

```
library(fGarch)

T=3000
    # For the example I simulate a GARCH
    #process parameters
    eta = 0.2 #eta = 0 is equivalent to Geometric Brownian Motion
    mu = 100 #the mean of the process

    #GARCH volatility model
    specs = garchSpec(model = list(omega = 0.000001, alpha = 0.5, beta = 0.4)) 
    sigma = garchSim(spec = specs, n = T)

    P_0 = mu #starting price, known
    P = rep(P_0,T)

    for(i in 2:T){
      P[i] = P[i-1] + eta * (mu - P[i-1]) + sigma[i] * P[i-1]
    }

    # Set the parameters :
para<-c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.7) # (beta_0,beta_1, beta_2, beta_3, r, gamma) 
    # Iteration to obtain the volatility associate to the model :

vol = c()
vol[1]=sd(P)
for (i in 2:length(P)){
      para_vol <- para[1:6]
      vol[i]=para_vol[1]+ (para_vol[2]*vol[i-1])+ (para_vol[3]/vol[i-1])*(P[i-1]-para_vol[5]-(para_vol[4]+para_vol[6])*vol[i-1])
      }
vol
```

This is an example where I simulate a GARCH (as data set). I am trying to extract the volatility associated with the Heston-Nandi model.

I know I'm using a lot of bad things for R, but I could not figure out a better solution. Are there any corrections or suggestions needed to improve this process?

Comment: This question has been [cross-posted on Quantitative Finance](http://quant.stackexchange.com/q/16235).

Answer (score 1):

First, in R we use `<-` for assignment. It has its advantages.

It is prefered that you don't use `T` and `F` as variable names as these are
aliases to `TRUE` and `FALSE`.

Instead of this `P <-  rep(P_0, T)` you could have `P <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = T)`.

This is just a suggestion: But there is no reason to not name your parameters:

```r
para <- c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.7) # (beta_0,beta_1, beta_2, beta_3, r, gamma)
para <- c(beta_0 = 0.1,  beta_1 = 0.2, beta_2 = 0.3, beta_4 = 0.4, r = 0.5, gamma = 0.7) # (beta_0,beta_1, beta_2, beta_3, r, gamma)
```

Then, you may access them like `para["gamma"]`, but not `para$gamma`.
Also, there is no need for `para_vol<-para[1:6]` in the loop, but I wager this is remnant
from other attempts.

In terms of performance, the pre-allocation I used did a 70 ms to 50 ms. Although,
I'm not confident in those numbers, as I did it fairly unscientifically.

Also, the referenced post shows a more direct way of calculating this.

Collapsed version of the code I ended up with:

```r
library(fGarch)

T <-  3000
# For the example I simulate a GARCH
#process parameters
eta <-  0.2 #eta = 0 is equivalent to Geometric Brownian Motion
mu <-  100 #the mean of the process

#GARCH volatility model
specs <-  garchSpec(model = list(
  omega = 0.000001,
  alpha = 0.5,
  beta = 0.4
))
sigma <-  garchSim(spec = specs, n = T)

# library(ggfortify)
# autoplot(sigma)

P_0 <- mu #starting price, known
# P <-  rep(P_0, T)
P <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = T)
P[1] <- P_0

for (i in 2:T) {
  P[i] <-  P[i - 1] + eta * (mu - P[i - 1]) + sigma[i] * P[i - 1]
}
# DOESN'T WORK
# P[-T] <-  P[-T] + eta * (mu - P[-T]) + sigma[-1] * P[-T]

# Set the parameters :
para <-
  c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.7) # (beta_0,beta_1, beta_2, beta_3, r, gamma)
# Iteration to obtain the volatility associate to the model :

vol <- vector("numeric", length = length(P))
vol[1] <-  sd(P)
for (i in 2:length(P)) {
  # para_vol <- para[1:6]
  vol[i] <-
    para_vol[1] + (para_vol[2] * vol[i - 1]) + (para_vol[3] /
                                                  vol[i - 1]) * (P[i - 1] - para_vol[5] - (para_vol[4] + para_vol[6]) * vol[i - 1])
}
vol

# autoplot(vol)
```